# Elements keeping original values in jQuery objects after PostBack

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, init, object-literal

I am using **ASP.NET 3.5** combined with the atrocious **UpdatePanel**, `jQuery.delegate()`, and **JavaScript** object literals.

I use `jQuery.delegate()` to persist the event handlers, which do get triggered after the **PostBack**, as expected.

The issue is with the **jQuery** objects stored in object literal properties on `init()` where they keep the values they had prior to the **ASP.NET PostBack**.

Here is my **JavaScript** :

## SFAIC

---

```js
SFAIC = 
{
    masterPages: { cs: "CS_", cp: "CP_" },
    contentPages: { cs: "CSContent_", cp: "CPContent_" },
    
    isSecurePage  : false,

    $body         : undefined,
    $container    : undefined,
    $updatePanel  : undefined,

    $textBox      : undefined,
    $errorLabel   : undefined
};
```

## SFAIC.init()

---

```js
SFAIC.init = function () 
{ 
    log( "--> SFAIC.init() fired" );

    var self = this; 

    self.$body        = $( "body" );
    self.$container   = self.$body.find( "#container" );
    self.$updatePanel = self.getCSMasterElement( "UpdatePanel1", self.$container );
    self.$textBox     = self.getContentElement( "TextBox1" );
    self.$errorLabel  = self.getContentElement( "ErrorLabel1" );
     
    self.$updatePanel.delegate( self.$textBox.selector, "blur", function () 
    { 
       self.validateRequired( self.$textBox, self.$errorLabel ); 
    });
    
    self.$textBox.focus();
};
```

## SFAIC.validateRequired()

---

```js
SFAIC.validateRequired = function ( $element, $errorLabel ) 
{
    if ( $element.val().length === 0 ) { $errorLabel.text( "Required" ); }
    else { $errorLabel.text( "" ); }
};
```

---

Given the above, when `SFAIC.init()` is fired, `self.textBox` is assigned to its jQuery object.  I guess herein lies my confusion.  I thought that when you call `.val()`, it would return the value of what's in that element right then.  In the case where you make a call to the server and change the value of the control which then comes back rendering the changed value of the element, it seems that the jQuery object doesn't know about that change?

Am I wrong here?

What do I need to do to keep a real-time reference to the element, so that I can get the current value after the page is posted back?

Edit request per **@DaveLong** :

## SFAIC.getCSMasterElement()

---

```js
SFAIC.getCSMasterElement = function ( id, $context ) 
{ 
    return SFAIC.getElement( SFAIC.masterPages.cs, id, $context ); 
};
```

## SFAIC.getCPMasterElement()

---

```js
SFAIC.getCPMasterElement = function ( id, $context ) 
{ 
    return SFAIC.getElement( SFAIC.masterPages.cp, id, $context ); 
};
```

## SFAIC.getContentElement()

---

```js
SFAIC.getContentElement = function ( id, $context ) 
{ 
    return SFAIC.getElement
    ( 
        ( SFAIC.isSecurePage ) ? SFAIC.contentPages.cp : SFAIC.contentPages.cs, 
        id, 
        $context 
    ); 
};
```

## SFAIC.getElement()

---

```js
SFAIC.getElement = function ( page, id, $context ) 
{
    selector = SFAIC.getElementIdSelector( page, id );
    
    return ( selector ) 
        ? ( $context && $context.length ) 
            ? $context.find( selector ) 
            : SFAIC.$body.find( selector )
        : undefined;
};
```

## SFAIC.getElementIdSelector()

---

```js
SFAIC.getElementIdSelector = function ( page, id ) 
{ 
    var prefix = SFAIC.getElementPrefix( page );
    return ( prefix && id ) ? "#" + prefix + id : undefined;
};
```

## SFAIC.getElementPrefix()

---

```js
SFAIC.getElementPrefix = function ( page ) 
{   
    switch ( page ) 
    {
        case SFAIC.masterPages.cs : return SFAIC.masterPages.cs;
        case SFAIC.masterPages.cp : return SFAIC.masterPages.cp + SFAIC.masterPages.cs;
        case SFAIC.contentPages.cs : return SFAIC.masterPages.cs + SFAIC.contentPages.cs;
        case SFAIC.contentPages.cp : return SFAIC.masterPages.cp + SFAIC.masterPages.cs + SFAIC.contentPages.cs + SFAIC.contentPages.cp;                
    }
};
```

Comment: Any chance you have a working example that we can see?

Comment: No, not at all. This is in dev at the moment and since it's ASP.NET, I can't exactly duplicate this with a jsFiddle.  I can tell you, though, I know for sure through output to `console.log`, that not only is it keeping the value of `self.textBox` before the PostBack, when it goes to set the `$errorLabel` in the `SFAIC.validateRequired()`, it's not changing the value on the screen.  Very odd behavior.

Comment: Hi Scott - can you post the "getContentElement()" function as I suspect that may be (at least partially) where your problem lies.

Comment: @Dave - I've had to update my original code to put back in and change some things due to your request.  The original code was a slimmed down pseudo code version of the real thing.  Per your request, I've added each function that is touched along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UpdatePanel removes the entire target from the DOM and replaces it with new markup from the response. It isn't that your vars are holding old values, it is that they are holding references to the original markup. You need to "reinitialize" in order to obtain references to the new nodes in the DOM.

Comment: Ok ... I was sensing that was the case when I researched further after @NitinJS' responses.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should re-init the objects when the ajax updatepanel request completes

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ReInitiate); 
     function ReInitiate(sender, args)
     {
        //re-initialize the objects 
        //add code here 
     } 
</script>
```

Cheers,
Nitin

Comment: My question seems to be more fundamental.  If this were this case, then everyone who used ASP.NET, UpdatePanels, and jQuery, would have to do this for every object inside the UpdatePanel.  My question lies in the fundamentals of the jQuery object.  Does it store the value of `val()` in the object, or when `val()` is called, does it go to the DOM and retrieve the value.  That's more in line with where my head is at right now.

Comment: If u see the [jquery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) Line 2031, val() actually retrieves values from DOM, cheers!

Comment: I figured as much ... just seems odd.  It's as if the javascript is interacting with the previous snapshot of the page before the PostBack even though the triggers are fired from the returned response.  So weird.

Comment: Curious, but why would I need to reinitialize my objects if they are pulling the values from the DOM?  I understand event handlers would be broken, but I use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) to persist my event handlers for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the solution I came up with was a customized version of Paul Irish's [Markup-based unobtrusive comprehensive DOM-ready execution](http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) and @NitinJS' / @Ethan's answers.

### *At the bottom of my JavaScript I added:*

```
UTIL = {

    fire : function(func, funcname) {

        var namespace = SFAIC;
        funcname = (funcname === undefined) ? "init" : funcname;

        if (func !== "" && 
            namespace[func] && 
            typeof namespace[func][funcname] == "function") { 

            namespace[func][funcname](); 

        }

    },

    loadEvents : function() {

        var bodyId = document.body.id;

        UTIL.fire("common");
        UTIL.fire(bodyId);

    }

};

// Fire events on initial page load.
UTIL.loadEvents();

// Fire events for partial postbacks.
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(UTIL.loadEvents);
```

### *In my MasterPage's aspx, I modified the body tag to:*

```
<body id="<%=bodyId%>">
```

### *In my MasterPage's code-behind declarations, I added:*

```
Public bodyId As String = String.Empty
```

### *In my MasterPage's code-behind Page.PreRender handler, I added:*

```
bodyId = MyBase.GetType.BaseType.Name
```